# Proof regarding limits

Tags: limits, proof-writing, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

[image]

Okay so I'm new to calculus and still trying to grasp what I can and cannot do, and was wondering if the way I showed my counter example is correct, notably the domain part..
Also I'm desperate for tips on how to prove/disprove these type of questions and I would be extremely thankful if you could show me different patterns of proofs as I want to absorb as much as I can!

Comment: Well that's the conundrum which beginners face in calculus: "what I can or cannot do". The blame is entirely on textbooks and curriculum designers. Just like when we say that $a+b=b+a$ is allowed (and $\sqrt{a+b} =\sqrt {a} +\sqrt{b} $ is **not**) in Algebra, someone should mention explicitly what is and what isn't allowed in calculus.

Comment: Also please [learn to use mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) (it's not difficult and the fonts used by it are so damn beautiful) instead of using images to post your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a great job :)

Writing $x \in {\Bbb R}\setminus \{x_0\}\{0\}$ is not defined.
You should have just written $x \in {\Bbb R}\setminus \{x_0\}$, where $x_0 = 0$.